# How to import an EJS file in a HTML file

Tags: javascript, express, xhtml, ejs

I am trying to include an EJS file in my XHTML file so that I could pass on the data to the managed bean.
I tried by including withing in script tag as     but i am not getting the value from the EJS file to XHTML file.
Could anyone please help me in the proper way to include an EJS file in HTML/ XHTML file.

Thanks,

```
ind.ejs

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Date is: </h1>       <%= new Date() %>
      Room Type is:           <%= checkindt %> <br /> 
     Room Type is:            <%= roomtype %> 
</body>
</html>
```

app.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/ind.ejs" > </script>
 <title>My App</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
   <script type="text/javascript" >
      function setValue(){
          alert('app.xhtml');
          alert('cindt is: '+ checkindt);
         document.getElementById('myForm.cindt').value = checkindt;
      }
  </script>
</head>
   <body>
       <div>My app</div>
       <form name="myForm" >
           Date:   <input type="text" name="cindt" />            
           <button id="submit" onclick="setValue();" />
       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better solution than using ejs, but I will attempt to answer this question anyways.

1) Download a browser compatible version of EJS. Try clicking [Here](http://embeddedjavascript.googlecode.com/files/ejs_1.0_developer.zip) to download or go [here](http://www.embeddedjs.com/getting_started.html).

2) Inlude it in you page:

```
<script src="ejs.js"></script>
<script>
 // your code here
</script>
```

3) Render/Compile it:

From text:

```
<script src="ejs.js"></script>
<script>
  var ejsResult = new EJS({
          text: "<div>Room number is: <%= roomnumber %> <br /> Room Type is: <%= roomtype %> </div>"
      }).render({roomnumber: "111", roomtype: "Suite"})

  someElement.innerHTML = ejsResult;
</script>
```

From a url:

```
<script src="ejs.js"></script>
<script>
  var ejsResult = new EJS({
          url: "templateLocation.ejs"
      }).render({roomnumber: "111", roomtype: "Suite"});

  someElement.innerHTML = ejsResult;
</script>
```